# Django unit testing: ValueError on GET url

Tags: django, unit-testing, authentication

I'm currently trying to run unit test using GET and POST on specific urls when my client is logged in.

I set my user and login like this:

```
 self.client = Client()
 self.client.login(username="test_user", password="test")  # Returns True
```

and then try to fetch for example:

```
response = self.client.get('/avantages/%s/register' % self.fst_benefit.id)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'avantages/1'
```

Nota: error does not raise whenever I do not use login on my self.client

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my own problem,

I wasn't enforcing int values as ids in my urls.py. So I just added [\d] to my id refering patterns.

More, I used reverse in order to generate the login url. It perfectly works now, whatever url i'm trying to use when I'm logged in.

```
my_url = reverse('my_view',
                 kwargs={'benefit_id': self.fst_benefit.id})
response = self.client.get(my_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to convert 'avantages/1' to an int, it appears that `Client` (whatever that is) expects the `login` method to be called with a single int, i.e. `self.fst_benefit.id`, not `'/avantages/%s/register' % self.fst_benefit.id`